# Can't get the addition correctly

Tags: javascript

I use React. shareTransferred is 0.03, but 1+shareTransferred returns 10.03 and shareTransferred+1 returns 0.031 when I see it from my web browse through console.log(), how to fix this problem?

Comment: maybe shareTransferred is a string and you concatenate them instead of doing addition? Try 1 + +shareTransferred

Comment: content from an input element is text, use `Number(text)` to convert it to a number

Comment: Yes, that's it. I have fixed it.